# Convert 2 digit year to 4 digit year swift

Tags: swift, date

I am new to swift and trying some date formats.

I have a 2 digit year(15) in Int32 format

I want to convert it to 4 digit year(2015) again assign to same var in Int32.

can someone share how to do this ?

I tried below:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YY"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(expirationYear)
    print(convertedDate)
```

But it gives error "Cannot convert from Int32 to NSDate"

Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with `print(2000+expirationYear)`?

Comment: You don't have a date, so you don't need a dateformatter, but if you ever do, use lowercase "yy" or "yyyy" for years.  "YY" is not what you think it is (it's complicated, but a common source of iOS bugs)

Comment: @Lashane how would it be localized if i use 2000+expirationYear ?

Comment: @user1452936 what do you mean by "localized"?

Comment: this code will have to run for many countries and date would be in different formats as per the locale. I need a way to convert my Int32 var into NSDate and then use NSDateFormatter locale thingy , convert it to yyyy and again assign to Int32

Comment: A year is not a date, even if you make it 2015. If you choose to make it 1st Jan 2015, in parts of the world that will be 2014. Why do you need to convert a year to a date - what are you going to do with it next?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
let year = 2015
let dateString = "\(year)-03-16"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString as String) {
    print("\(date)")
}
```